# How can I know if a network is secure before connecting to it?

Tags: raspbian, networking, debian, archlinux, linux

before connecting to a network i want to know if it needs a password or not like in the network manager.

The security of every network

any commands will be welcomed

Comment: This sounds more like a general linux / networking question, rather than something specific to the PI, non?

Comment: Paul's right.  You'd be better off asking this on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: the architecture of the PI and its OS is not similar to  the other architecture so maybe the response would be different for every OS and System !

Comment: @user12448 Actually, it isn't all that different. While it **is** true that the Pi runs on an ARM chip, this would still be a general Linux/Networking question, as Raspbian hasn't been changed very much from its Debian base, just adapted to be slightly lighter and run on ARMv6. This *would* fit better on [unix.se]. Please don't feel we are picking on you personally, this is just how Stack Exchange runs. The users moderate the content and keep it useful and site-specific, and although you *are* using a Pi, this is related to Linux in general, as Raspbian is simply a debian (linux) port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Paul and user12448 have indicated, this is a generic Linux question, and the answer is the same for Rasbian on the Raspberry Pi. To get a list of available networks you can use the iwlist command:

```
iwlist wlan0 scan
```

This will give you output something like this:

```
wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: 00:26:2A:F6:24:53
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=51/70  Signal level=-59 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"network_name"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                              36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000010a52e1c237
                    Extra: Last beacon: 119492ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000942616C6C797279616E
                    IE: Unknown: 010582848B960C
                    IE: Unknown: 030101
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0104
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 32080C1218243048606C
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
```

If it says "Encryption key:on" it will need some sort of password. What type of encryption is later on in the scan results. In this case it says "WPA2" and "TKIP"/"CCMP"/"PSK", which is essentially standard security for a few years ago.

Comment: yes this is actually What I come with : (sudo iwlist wlan0 scan | grep 'Group Cipher' | cut -d: -f2) but the problem is how to differentiate between a secure one(need password) and another one not secure(don't need password) because my command is useless

Comment: That's the "Encryption key:on" bit. If no password is needed it will read instead "Encryption key:off".